# Does the RGBSpectrum class in pbrt store RGB color values directly, not power?

Tags: pbrt

I had a hard time to understand this.

I thought `*Spectrum` classes (`SampledSpectrum`, specifically) store power (SI unit: W) in them and when I want RGB colors from them, I have to use some complicated method to convert power to XYZ then to RGB.

I thought `RGBspectrum` is just a three-sample `SampledSpectrum`, but it seems not ... If it stores power (W), how could its `ToRGB` method directly return its power?

```cpp
void ToRGB(Float *rgb) const {
    rgb[0] = c[0];
    rgb[1] = c[1];
    rgb[2] = c[2];
}
```

Does `RGBSpectrum` directly store color values in it? If that so, how could we use color to calculate radiance instead of power?